# Get specific <li> tag values using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to get
"Pen" , "All Pen" values.

Here is what i tried :-
Please take a look at the code & share your thoughts
Please take a look at the code & share your thoughts

```js
var filtered_category = jQuery('ul.pc_filter_middle-stage2-list ul li:first-child').contents().get(0).nodeValue;
    var parent_filtered_category = jQuery('ul.pc_filter_middle-stage2-list ul li:first-child').parents().find('#accordionItemhide li').contents().get(0).nodeValue; 
    
    console.log(filtered_category);
        console.log(parent_filtered_category);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-container active" style="display: block;">
    <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list-title"><li><strong>Category</strong></li></ul>

    <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list">

      <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
        <li style="font-weight: normal;">Pencil<span>(2200)</span><img src="/media/images/default/filter_arrow_down_white.svg" alt=""><arrow></arrow></li>

        <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category1">
          <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
              <li data-value="2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active" aria-selected="false">Pencils<span>(200)</span></li><li data-value="8" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active">Pencils<span>(300)</span></li>                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
        <li style="font-weight: normal;">Pen<span>(1200)</span></li>

        <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category2">
          <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
            <li data-value="All Pen" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">All Pen<span>(10000)</span></li>
      </div>

    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Let me know if any questions, it seems simple but i am not getting it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first try to fix your HTML. Considering I don't know what your program or site does I just refactor everything you had:

```js
   $(document).ready(() => {
    const okFilter = $('.ok-filter');
    const bodyContent = okFilter.find('.ok-filter__ul--body');
    const secondCategory = bodyContent.find('.ok-filter_wrapper--category:nth-child(2)');
    const secondCategoryListElements = secondCategory.find('.ok-filter__li');
    
    const values = secondCategoryListElements.get().map((li) => li.childNodes[0].nodeValue, []);
    
    console.log(values);
   });
```

```css
.ok-filter--active {
  display: block;
}
.ok-filter__li--title {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.ok-filter__li--item {
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok-filter ok-filter--active">

  <ul class="ok-filter__ul ok-filter__ul--header">
    <li class="ok-filter__li ok-filter__li--title">Category</li>
  </ul>
  
  <ul class="ok-filter__ul ok-filter__ul--body">
  
    <div class="ok-filter__wrapper ok-filter_wrapper--category">
      <li class="ok-filter__li ok-filter__li--item">Clothing<span>(2200)</span><img src="/media/images/default/filter_arrow_down_white.svg" alt=""><arrow></arrow></li>
      
       <div class="ok-filter__wrapper ok-filter__wrapper--sub-category">
        <ul class="ok-filter__ul" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
          <li class="ok-filter__li ok-filter__li--active" data-value="2" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">Bodysuit<span>(200)</span></li>
          <li class="ok-filter__li ok-filter__li--active" data-value="8" tabindex="-1" role="option">Graphic Tees<span>(300)</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ok-filter__wrapper ok-filter_wrapper--category">
      <li class="ok-filter__li ok-filter__li--item">Shoes<span>(1200)</span></li>

      <div class="ok-filter__wrapper ok-filter__wrapper--sub-category">
        <ul  class="ok-filter__ul" role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
          <li class="ok-filter__li" data-value="All Shoes" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">All Shoes<span>(10000)</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

In the script section, you have an example of how you can get the requested values. I separated them using the `find()` function to give you more control & understanding of how to reach them. I have to be honest with you. If you aren't planning to support IE then using jquery only slows you down. You could have used `querySelector()` & `querySelectorAll()` instead.

Secondly, try to get data from text nodes is a really bad practice. If you want a value that is altered for the user you could have used an attribute to store that data in the given element or using the `<data>` element from HTML5. You could also just have wrapped it into a `<span>` tag to make sure you selected the correct element.

Good luck

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues in your selector.

1. Since the attribute *id* is unique, you can directly use that in the selector.
2. You can use `text()` to get the text content.

Try the following way:

```js
var filtered_category = jQuery('ul.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list ul li:first-child').text();
var parent_filtered_category = jQuery('#accordionItemhide li').text();

console.log(filtered_category);
console.log(parent_filtered_category);

var shows = jQuery('.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper:eq(1) li:eq(0)').text();
console.log(shows);

var all_shows = jQuery('.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper:eq(1) ul li:eq(0)').text();
console.log(all_shows);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-container active" style="display: block;">
  <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list-title"><li><strong>Category</strong></li></ul>

  <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list">

    <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
      <li style="font-weight: normal;">Clothing<span>(2200)</span><img src="/media/images/default/filter_arrow_down_white.svg" alt=""><arrow></arrow></li>

      <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category1">
        <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
            <li data-value="2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active" aria-selected="false">Bodysuit<span>(200)</span></li><li data-value="8" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active">Graphic Tees<span>(300)</span></li>                
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
      <li style="font-weight: normal;">Shoes<span>(1200)</span></li>

      <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category2">
        <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
          <li data-value="All Shoes" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">All Shoes<span>(10000)</span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please check updated question. i want "Shoes" , "All Shoes" values.

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be solve your problem:

```
$('.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper').each(function() {
      console.log($(this).find('li').text())
    });
```

Using .each() we can go through the elements and finally find your childs.

Comment: Please check updated question. i want "Shoes" , "All Shoes" values.

Comment: Any thoughts ??

Comment: Try this bro



`let list = $('.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper').get(1)
            console.log($(list).find('li').length)
           for(var i = 0; i < $(list).find('li').length; i++){
               let elem = $(list).find('li').get(i)
               console.log($(elem).text().replace(/\s/g,''))
           }`

Answer (score 0):

A function like the one in the below example would be helpful.

The order of the items in the output, is one to one related, to the order of the items in the array of search terms.

So for a search array `['Clothing','Bodysuit','Shoes','All Shoes']` the output would be `["2200","200","1200","10000"]`.

```js
function findValues(searchTerms) {
let search = new RegExp('^('+searchTerms.join('|')+')','i');
return lis = Object.values($('.ok_filter_middle-stage2-list li')).filter(x => search.test(x.textContent)).map(x => $(x).find('span').text().replace(/(\(|\))/g,''));
}

let out = findValues(['Clothing','Bodysuit']);
console.log(out);

out = findValues(['Shoes','All Shoes']);
console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-container active" style="display: block;">
          <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list-title"><li><strong>Category</strong></li></ul>

          <ul class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list">
            
            <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
              <li style="font-weight: normal;">Clothing<span>(2200)</span><img src="/media/images/default/filter_arrow_down_white.svg" alt=""><arrow></arrow></li>
              
              <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category1">
                <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
                    <li data-value="2" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active" aria-selected="false">Bodysuit<span>(200)</span></li><li data-value="8" tabindex="-1" role="option" class="active">Graphic Tees<span>(300)</span></li>                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            
            <div id="accordionItemhide" class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-list_wrapper">
              <li style="font-weight: normal;">Shoes<span>(1200)</span></li>
              
              <div class="ok_filter_middle-stage2-category-list sub-category2">
                <ul role="listbox" tabindex="0" aria-label="folder list">
                  <li data-value="All Shoes" tabindex="-1" role="option" aria-selected="false">All Shoes<span>(10000)</span></li>
            </div>
            
          </ul>
        </div>
```